# Latin -que suffix in romance languages

Tags: latin, romance-languages

In Latin the suffix -que can be used to mean "and". For example:

> Fames sitis**que** (Hunger and thirst)

Are there any modern Romance languages that use the suffix -que or something similar to it?

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://limbaromana.org/en/2014/08/introduction-to-the-etymological-dictionary-of-the-romanian-language/) claims that Romanian **şi** (and) derives from "-que", but [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C8%99i) derives it from "sic" (thus). (Being Wiktionary, of course without any sources.) To me, going from *thus* to *and* seems like a big leap, but I don't know anything for sure about that. Edit: Apparently not that giant a leap, see comments.

As far as actual enclitics go, I'm not aware of any Romance language that uses one, but I only know about the 'big' ones (Italian, French, Castilian, Portuguese, Romanian).

Comment: From *thus* to *and* via *also* is not a big leap at all. For what it's worth, most Slavic languages derive *also* from *thus* (common Slavic `tak`: "thus", "so", "in this way") in various ways (Russian: `также`, Czech: `také`, Serbian/Croat: `takođe`), and Slavic languages have been a significant influence on Romanian.

Comment: @NikolayErshov Not to mention English *also*, which of course is all + so. You are quite right.

Comment: *-qu-* and *-gu-* yield *p* and *b*, respectively, in Romanian. As far as a official sources for *sic > si* are concerned, [all](http://www.dex.ro/si/33319) Romanian [dictionaries](http://www.dex.ro/si/508009) confirm it.

Comment: The irony being with *also* that it should technically, and I guess in practice deep non literary registers, be *a'so* (cp. German *auch so*) , same as *as* (cp. German *als*), the l being hylercorrect and the root most liquely a kin to the very *-que* in question. Inb4 German *auch* is cp. Nl. *ok* "and" and L. *augustus*, not Go. *-hw* and L. *-que*, I have two words to say, one of them being "you!"

Comment: At least as of today, wiktionary lists a source, and I have verified that it supports the derivation of şi from sic: https://dexonline.ro/definitie/%C8%99i/definitii

Comment: @SirCornflakes and what is tbeir take on *sīc* < *sei-ke*? Epistemologically, *\*-ke* derives from Latin and then some. Ontologically, it may or may not be akin to Greek *kai* rather than Latin *-que*, but who really knows?

Comment: They don't go beyond *sīc* as far as I can tell. Which is reasonable for an etymological dictionary of Romanian.

Comment: @SirCornflakes - Anyway, this answer is about the (imaginary) etymology of *și* from *-que* (that link is dead anyway), while the question is about the use of a suffix to say ”yes”. I have found 3 Romanian words where *și* somehow acted as a suffix explaining the etymology, although we cannot say it is a suffix now (but is part of the ”new” word).

Comment: My comment was more directed at the here popular Wiktionary bashing in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If 'something similar' to Latin *-que* is good enough for you, present-day Spanish *conmi**go*** contains an old preposition or prepositional clitic suffix **-cum** hidden under the current from **-go**. [Our *conmigo* actually derives from *cum mecum*, where the *-cum* part of *mecum* was originally an adposition/a syntactic affix meaning 'with' arguably similar to the *-que* clitic meaning 'and'. That construction was, of course, redundant, a remnant of the stage at which late spoken Latin was becoming a head-complement language, what Romance languages soon were to develop into, but still contained important residues, mainly in VPs and PPs, of the earlier complement-head phase]. Less obviously, present-day Spanish *quisqui*, as in *todo quisqui* (= every body), *cada quisqui* (= each person), is a reflex of Latin *quis-que* (originally perhaps = somebody **else**).

Comment: "Spanish" quisqui is not a "real" Spanish word; it is a Latin word used in Spanish.

Comment: So are "quid", "quidam", "curriculum", "status quo" and a host of expressions that are both common in educated speech and listed in the official dictionary of the Real Academia Española. I assure you that "todo quisqui" and "cada quisqui" are absolutely normal in educated speech, and are as much part of the Spanish dictionary as thousands of words originally borrowed from Latin, Greek, English, French, Italian, and many other languages.

Comment: My point is simply that a Latin loan word is not evidence for a productive suffix -qui in Spanish. Also, in linguistics we distinguish between a "reflex" (your last sentence) and a "borrowing".

Answer (score 2):

Two French/Italian examples :

o **French "quiconque"** (anyone) < Latin quicumque (anyone)

quicumque = qui + cum + -que

Italian : **chiunque**

o **French "chacun"** (each one) < Vulgar Latin "cascunu" < Latin "quisque unus" (every one), maybe mixed with Ancient Greek "unum kata unum" (one by one).

quisque = quis + -que

Comment: "unum" is Greek?

Comment: I bet the Wikipedia page I read supposed something like "unum κατὰ unum" (http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chacun).

Comment: Old answer, but neither *quiconque* nor *chiunque* continues *quicumque* or *-que* in some other way (they're both ultimately *qui* + *umquam*), and *unum cata* (not *kata*) *unum* is obviously Latin; Greek κατά was borrowed into Late Latin.

Answer (score 0):

Considering not the Latin form *-que*, but just a word meaning "and" that would somehow be present as a suffix, Romanian *și* appears as an etymological base in this way.

Without being an actual suffix that would work like in Latin in modern Romanian, the form [*și*](https://ro.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C8%99i#Etimologie) (and) from Latin *sic* (which gave *yes* in other Romance languages) may be considered to have acted as a suffix (maybe in [Proto-Romanian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Romanian)?) that explains the etymology of a few words (conjunctions, determiners), although it doesn't act *now* as a suffix.

[*Același*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/acela%C8%99i) (singular; plural: *aceiași*, fem.:*aceeași*, fem.,plural: *aceleași*) (the same) < *[acela](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/acela%C8%99i)* (fem. *aceea*) (that one) + *și* (and). – Genitive/dative forms: *aceluiași, aceleiași, acelorași* (to the same).

[*Totuși*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/totu%C8%99i) (however) < *tot* (all) + *și*

[*Deși*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/de%C8%99i) (although) < [*de*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/de#Romanian) (of, from, if etc) + *și*

Other words like [*însuși*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%AEnsu%C8%99i) (himself) or *însăși* (herself) are formed with a different *-și* (from [Latin *se*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/se#Latin)).

Answer (score -6):

French has [*ouais*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/ouais) in various senses of "yeah" (Collins Dictionary). Wartburg (FEW vol. 4 [p. 444](https://lecteur-few.atilf.fr/index.php/page/lire/e/184827))
derives it from *hoc*. See also language d'oc and language d'oil. Anyway, like *hic*, I guess that the coda is from a particle reconstructed with a voiced velar, possibly aspirated palatal (de Vaan: *hic*). This one is poorly understood. It is otter nonsense to equate *ouais* with *-que*, even when *nequbi / necubi* alternates the way it does, however.

The question concernes *-que* at the end of conjunctions. The major romance languages use a form of *et* "and" in enumeration instead. Fr. *aussi* "also, too" is from *sic*, so that's perhaps your best guess, analoguous to *hic, hoc* (hickery doo).

Ultimately it is not clear what the question is asking. As a matter of methodology, the vocabulary knowledge concerns the individual languages. The suffix being productive anywhere wouldn't really be a linguistic concern by the rules of this bord. As a matter of gaining a better understanding of the origins of the suffix, comparable to *quisque*, a broader view of Vulgar Latin is required. Latin.SE is [over there](https://latin.stackexchange.com), but evidence of spoken Latin is scarce, of course.